# POST request taking long time in cef sharp

Tags: wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

We have a web application (UI wrapped in CEF + WPF) where we make a JavaScript POST request to the server. The POST request only has query string parameters and no request body. The server takes up to 5 minutes to process and send a small response back. Even when the server sends the response back (lets say 4 minutes), the request is still shown as pending in the Inspector (and success callback is not executed). Only after 8-10 minutes the response is shown as complete (and success callback is executed).

When we check the time distribution of the finished request call, it says that everything finished in 4 minutes which is very strange. This behavior is not happening in Google chrome browser. Any advise on what could be going wrong.

Comment: Check if issue reproduces in cefclient and if so report issue in upstream CEF.